# Image non-resized partition from a large SD

Tags: raspbian-jessie, image, backup, partition

I burnt a 2GB OS image on a 16GB sd card and went thru the whole configuration process (a good half day of work to adapt it to our needs) **except** for the resizing of the partition.

I would now, before expanding the filesystem and copying the databases on the SD, like to get a .img of the SD card for backup purposes. More precisely, I want to back up the 2GB partition of it containing the configured OS and not the whole card`s 16GB (of which 14 unformatted).

How to?

thank you

Comment: Please state a reason for downvoting - this is a commong problem when employing RPi in an industrial setting and has no clear answer on the internet.

Comment: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/47773/disable-auto-file-system-expansion-in-new-jessie-image-2016-05-10

Comment: Not really relevant, I did not expand the image. I am looking for a way to take an image of the SD card with the unexpanded, configured OS without  ending up imaging also the 14 GB of unallocated space.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Re-writing answer adhering to Stackechange`s guidelines:

"trimming" an image is is quite easy, it takes just two linux commands -

First, determine the size of the actual partition of your interest inside the image

Second, trim it.

Be sure you have read-write permission to the disk partition containing the image file of you interest (i.e. if you are a windows user and are using a live linux distro just for this operation, mount your windows partition with r/w permissions) then run the command:

`$ fdisk -l /filelocationofmyimage/myimage.img`

this will return information in the format

`Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System`

Write down the **highest end block value amongst the partition(s) of your interest contained in the image file** lets call this value mypartendvalue

Trim the image running `truncate --size=$[(mypartendvalue+1)*512]/filelocationofmyimage/myimage.img`

The "+1" is needed since blocks are counted from zero and the parametrs we are passing to truncate is a size so without the +1 we`d lose one block.

Comment: If you had posted some information (what OS, output of `sudo fdisk -l` and what system you were using) you may have got an answer. The first is wrong for SD, the second is a clumsy kludge.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Thanks.

Comment: roger- fixing that now