# Disable filesystem expand during boot for Ubuntu Server 16.04

Tags: pi-3, ubuntu, filesystem

I am attempting to get a sub-4gb image to retain its image size on my rpi regardless of the sdcard size. I am looking at using the ubuntu server image built by Ryan Finnie [ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz) from the [ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)

The suggestion in [Temporarily disable expand filesystem during first boot](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/56621/temporarily-disable-expand-filesystem-during-first-boot/69945#69945) by goldilocks of disabling of `init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh`
 from `/boot/cmdline.txt` works on Ubuntu Mate.

But the server image does not have the `init=/usr/lib/raspi-config/init_resize.sh`  in `/boot/cmdline.txt` - but first boot expands the image to the max capacity of the card.

Does anyone know where the partition resize is triggered on this ubuntu server image?

Comment: Where are you downloading this image from?  [Is it this one?](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/16.04/release/ubuntu-16.04.2-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi2.img.xz)

Comment: That was latest official release, although it's for the rpi2.  The [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi#Ubuntu_16.04_LTS_.27classic.27) mentions an [unofficial rpi3 port](http://www.finnie.org/software/raspberrypi/ubuntu-rpi3/ubuntu-16.04-preinstalled-server-armhf+raspi3.img.xz).  Are you using that one?

Comment: @Hydraxan14 Yes, that is the one I am using as unfortunately the official one doesnt boot up on rpi 3 yet. I have updated the question to reflect this now.

Comment: `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_resizefs.py` looks suspect.  Now I just gotta figure out how it's getting called...

Comment: The `growpart` answer from @fskj should be marked correct.

Comment: @xalorous - I moved on to dietpi for a compact <2G and zippy experience. Now I no longer need to have a small OS footprint so I am on stock raspbian and on RPI4-4G its not much different from dietpi. But based on your recommendation I will accept fskj answer - without testing/verifying  though ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expansion of the partition is done by the *growpart* module of *cloud-init*.

Preventing cloud-init from extending the partition size can be done by adding the following lines to a *user-data* *cloud-config* YAML file:

```
growpart:
  mode: false
```

For the Ubuntu Server 21.04 Raspberry pi images, the lines above should be added to the `user-data` file on the boot partition.

Comment: I would like to add that adding `resize_rootfs: false` does NOT work. But this does. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

### cloud-init

The usual raspi-config script that resizes the root filesystem on boot isn't in this Ubuntu image.

The only init-related resize program I could find was `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_resizefs.py`.
This is apparently part of the Ubuntu `cloud-init` package, and has a function that will resize the root filesystem on boot.

The `cloud-init` package has a configuration file in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` which contains:

```
# The modules that run in the 'init' stage
cloud_init_modules:
 - migrator
 - ubuntu-init-switch
 - seed_random
 - bootcmd
 - write-files
 - growpart
 - resizefs
 - set_hostname
 - update_hostname
 - update_etc_hosts
 - ca-certs
 - rsyslog
 - users-groups
 - ssh
```

Notice `resizefs`?  That's probably what's triggering the resize.

---

### Disabling

Removing `resizefs` from that config file might be sufficient, or you can just disable `cloud-init`.

The installed version of `cloud-init` (0.7.7) was the first version to include an [easy way to completely disable it](https://bugs.launchpad.net/cloud-init/+bug/1513609):

```
 This is fix-committed now with systemd.
2 ways to disable cloud-init and stop any bottlenecks it would put in place during boot:
 a.) touch /etc/cloud/cloud-init.disabled
 b.) boot with cloud-init=disabled on kernel command line.
```

Comment: thanks for the research Hydraxan14... I will test out the cloud-init=disabled and report back asap.

Comment: Strangely, after booting with cloud-init=disabled in the cmdline.txt I am unable to login with username "ubuntu", password "ubuntu" - here is the comdline.txt "net.ifnames=0 dwc_otg.lpm_enable=0 console=ttyAMA0,115200 console=tty1 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2 rootfstype=ext4 elevator=deadline cloud-init=disabled rootwait"

Comment: I think one of cloud-init's jobs is to set up a [temporary 'ubuntu' user.](https://serverfault.com/q/440618) So maybe completely disabling it isn't the best idea after all...

Comment: @sith: yes, cloud-init creates the `ubuntu` user. If you want to just disable the partition resize, you can either comment the ` - resizefs` line, or do as @fsjk suggested in his answer

Comment: `growpart` needs to be stopped.  If the partition does not grow, the resizefs has nothing to do.  Alternatively there would be a basic way to inject custom parameters for growpart.  SO instead of expanding to the full size, I could force it to expand to x GB or y% instead.  My understanding is that cloud-init can be used to do this, on systems installed from iso or kickstart style install.  Just parameterize the desired final size and pop the customized file into the cloud-init config as teh deployment is started.  But this is RPi deploying over MicroSD using a static image.